# Set interval not working

Tags: jquery

I have function setinterval & clear interval but not work

```
$(".play").toggle(
    function() {
        clearInterval(okey);
        $( ".play" ).addClass("pause");    
    },
    function() {
        $( ".play" ).removeClass("pause");
        setInterval(okey);
    }
);
```

Comment: RTFM ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Comment: jQuery's `toggle` is deprecated and removed, or at least the version of `toggle` you're using is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call a function within setInterval and clearInterval methods. And add a timer within setInterval. For example 3000 = 3 seconds.

Example:

```
setInterval(myFunc(){alert("Hello")}, 3000);
```